Bouncing ball is glitched
I have problem with the bouncing ball, while creating it using class. The ball move but it stuck at the bottom of the page. Please help!!
Thank you!!!
The ball move but it stuck at the bottom of the page.
class particle{
  constructor(x,y,r){
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.r=r;
  }
  
  bounce(xSpeed, ySpeed){
    this.xSpeed = xSpeed;
    this.ySpeed = ySpeed;
    
    if (this.x < 0 || this.x > width) {
        this.xSpeed *= -1;
    
    if (this.y < 0 || this.y > height) {
        this.ySpeed *= -1;
    }

    this.x += this.xSpeed;
    this.y += this.ySpeed;

  }
  
  display(){
    fill(0,255,0);
    stroke(0);
    strokeWeight(1);
    circle(this.x,this.y,this.r);
  }
}

let balloon;
function setup(){
  createCanvas(windowWidth,windowHeight);
  balloon = new particle(100, 100, 100);
  
}

function draw(){
  background(245);
  
  balloon.bounce(5,5);
  balloon.display();
 
  }


It's because you put the initial xSpeed and ySpeed as input parameter of the bounce() function. I changed it so that the xSpeed and ySpeed now are initiated only once and later it gets changed based on the ball position, just like you intended.


class particle
{
  constructor(x,y,r,xSpeed,ySpeed)
  {
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.r=r;
    this.xSpeed = xSpeed;
    this.ySpeed = ySpeed;
  }
  
  bounce()
  {
    if (this.x < 0 || this.x > width)
    {
        this.xSpeed *= -1;
    }
    
    if (this.y < 0 || this.y > height)
    {
        this.ySpeed *= -1;
    }

    this.x += this.xSpeed;
    this.y += this.ySpeed;
  }
  
  display()
  {
    fill(0,255,0);
    stroke(0);
    strokeWeight(1);
    circle(this.x,this.y,this.r);
  }
}

let balloon;
  
function setup()
{
  createCanvas(windowWidth,windowHeight);
  balloon = new particle(100, 100, 100, 5, 5);
}

function draw()
{
  background(245);
  
  balloon.bounce();
  balloon.display();
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>



